# How to calculate percentage for rows based on total sums?

Tags: jasper-reports, percentage

Price is represented by `$F{price}` and I created a variable that sums the prices of each item to get the total price `$V{total_price}`, both of them are `java.Math.BigDecimal`.

I read a few posts that suggested changing the `Evaluation Time` property to `AUTO` for the total `text field` which I've done but percentage is calculated on the cumulative sum at each item hence I get 100 for the percentage of the first item and so on. How can I get the total price at once at when evaluating for the percentage of each item?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 4):

Yes you are close, auto should be used on percentage textField.

As far as I have understood you have this variable, to sum up the price's

```
<variable name="total_price" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{price}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

To get your percentage field just add a textField with `evaluationTime="auto"` where you divide the `$F{price}` with `$V{total_price}`

> **Auto** - Each variable participating in the text field expression is evaluated at a time corresponding to its reset type. **Fields are evaluated Now**. This evaluation type should be used for expressions that combine values evaluated **at different times**, like the percentage out of a total.

**Example**

```
<textField evaluationTime="Auto" pattern="#,##0.00 %">
    <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="e88223c7-12b6-401d-80b7-6c8341773027"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{price}.doubleValue()/$V{total_price}.doubleValue()]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: `evaluationTime="Auto"` - I really like this legal "hack". It was something crazy to use hacks with Map ... ))